# What should I do with these branches at the bottom of my tree?

Tags: trees, grafting, willow

I recently purchased a [Hakuro Nishiki](https://www.gardenia.net/plant/salix-integra-hakuro-nishiki-willow) Willow (tree) from a nearby nursery. When it was delivered I realized it had a set of new branches coming out of the base of the tree, that look way different from the leaves and branches at the top.

I've seen some grafts before, and was wondering if these are branches coming out of the graft rootstock? Should I prune these to help the grafted plant (scion?) grow healthier?

Are these trees even grafted, or am I witnessing some other phenomena?[image: here's a photo]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If does not *appear* to be *obviously* grafted, but the old scars of previously removed suckers indicate that it will quite happily make itself into a multi-stemmed bush rather than a tree if you don't prune off the suckers.

So, if you want a 1-trunk tree, cut them off.

*I'm a bit concerned that the soil level does not appear to be equal to the soil level it was in before, based on roots sitting above the soil and the color change on the bark. Trees do NOT like having that level changed, in general.*

Comment: Tearing them off is supposed to be more effective at those suckers growing back, as opposed to cutting.  In my own experience, I find this to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually answered to you in a different forum, but nonetheless. Since it's unclear what roots these are, I'd first dig in and see the difference in rooting systems, then when it's clear that this is not some weird growth on the Salix Integra, you could prune it away according to [this pruning method](https://www.gardenfocused.co.uk/shrub/salix-integra-hakuro-nishiki.php). Ecnerwal Also knows quite a bit about these plants to kudos to him.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).